# Starting up SignalR client is very slow

Tags: signalr

`$.connection.hub.start().done` takes 5 seconds to startup in production, works fine in dev.

Server 2012 and IIS 7.5

I remember another user had the same problem
[Hub.start - wait for finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369495/hub-start-wait-for-finish)

Comment: I found the answer, I'm behind a proxy https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/601#issuecomment-8115023

Comment: can this be fixe without enforcing long time polling?

Comment: if you have lots of resources on the page - images etc. - check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783480/signalr-connection-blocked-until-page-images-load

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

SignalR tried to connect to WebSocket but fails or your server does not have WebSocket Protocol for IIS installed.
Then it tries to use serverSentEvents and it returned timeout after 5 second
Only then it established longPolling

Thus you can try install WebSocket Protocol or remove serverSentEvents from transport options