# SignalR Connection Blocked Until page images load

Tags: javascript, callback, signalr, block

this is my signalr hub connection :

```
  chat = $.connection.chat;
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
     // problem is here 
     // this part is waiting for full page load.!
  });
```

I have a `<img src='BAD SERVER'/>`sometimes take one minute to load successfully.
and the connection won't start until the images completely loads.

How can I make signalR to start before the page load completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
chat = $.connection.chat;
$.connection.hub.start({ waitForPageLoad: false }).done(function () {
 // problem is here 
 // this part is waiting for full page load.!
});
```